# Eclipse multi editor window copy + paste + undo + redo + delete

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-pdt

Recently started using Eclipse (4.2.2) with PDT for PHP dev. Having some issues if I have multiple editor containers open. Also I'm using Ubuntu, so dont know if that has any baring on it.

I like to drag out some of the tabs onto other screens giving them a windowed container outside of the main IDE. When I do this, copy and paste does not work on the child window, and instead acts like the cursor is still on the main code container.

If I have multiple editor containers within the original IDE window its fine, the problem only manifests itself when I drag the container into its own window.

*Just noticed, it also wont let me undo / redo, or press 'delete' without having the same effect on the parent window. backspace however is fine*

Is this a bug or 'feature'? And any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if inside of dragging an existing editor tab out into a new window, go to the "Window" menu and select "new editor". Then drag that out and things would work as we expect them to.

FYI - This does not appear to be Ubuntu specific as I have the same problem on OSX 10.8.5 running Eclipse Juno SR2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a long standing bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401835

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any way to work around it other than restarting Eclipse.